I can't get multiple values out of my RSS feed for pre-defined field Author name
I'm really new to this but have managed everything so far other than to pull out multiple authors.  I am importing from a url with RSS/Atom parser and the XML is structured like so:
<author><name>Bob</name></author>
<author><name>John</name></author>
<author><name>James</name></author>

I've set the field to multiple values and I have tried tampering with the feed but to no avail yet.
I understand that using RSS/Atom in Drupal I can only use the Pre-defined fields - is it that Drupal will only accept one Author name?
I've also tried creating a feed from an uploaded XML file so I can tinker with it, but it's the same result - only 1 author is output.
